# Readymade solution to parse mailto URLs in Cocoa?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, mailto

I have a `UIWebView` in an iPhone app and want to intercept structured mailto-URLs like `mailto:email@address.com?subject=foo&body=bar` in order to display a `MFMailComposeViewController` inside the app instead of handing over the URL to Mail.app.

Now it would be great if all properties of `MFMailComposeViewController` would be automatically set according to the mailto URL. Unfortunately, `MFMailComposeViewController` does not accept a mailto URL but requires to set the individual properties.

NSURL apparently is not of great help either. Are you aware any existing code so that I don't have to write the parser code? ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wrote my own solution: https://gist.github.com/667952
It's a bit ugly and probably not 100% foolproof in terms of RFC support, but as long as the syntax of the mailto URLs is under your own control, it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Ortwin, thanks for your code. I forked it to add a check on the canSendMail method and to add it as a category of MFMailComposeViewController. Please, find it here: https://gist.github.com/788075

Comment: Thanks. I agree, it's probably a better design to add this as a category to `MFMailComposeViewController`. Even cleaner would be to use a `NSURL` parameter instead of `NSURLRequest`.

Comment: You are right about the NSURL, I didn't notice it. :-/ I've fixed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You want [`NSDataDetector`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Besides the fact that `NSDataDetector` is iOS 4.x only and I need OS 3.x compatibility, how would I use it to accomplish the task? I understand that NSDataDetectors are good to recognize e.g. email addresses in arbitrary text. This is not what I want. I already have a structured mailto link like the following: `mailto:email@address.com?subject=foo&body=bar`. So it's just about splitting the parameters and filling fields. Not a big deal actually but I was still too lazy to write it again if it existed already.

Comment: @Ortwin: if it isn't available on your operating system, then the question of how to use it is moot. Like the story of Napoleon and the cannon.

Comment: Not quite. I'd be truly interested since I'm not really familiar with data detectors yet. For this case, I wrote some code to solve the problem. See my answer.

Comment: As he said, NSDataDetectors don't do what Ortwin wants; the data already *is* detected.